# SEO for form tag

Tags: javascript, forms, seo

I am trying to make my dynamic content visible to search engines. I understand that I need to use `method="get"` for best results. Security is not a concern for this portion of my forum, I'm simply reloading a division of the home web page with read-only content from a database.

It works but I want Google to be able to crawl the custom content which is reloaded in the home page after pressing various buttons.

So, for SEO am I doomed if I use the following:

```
    <form name="aspnetForm" method="get" action="default.aspx" 
    onkeypress="javascript:return  WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 
    'ctl00_btnLoginImage')" id="aspnetForm">
```

I'm concerned that using JavaScript ensures that all subsequent content is invisible to robots/spiders. I noticed that my URL does not change after key presses as I had hoped - it remains the home directory.

Comment: Google cannot crawl forms event get methods because it never submits the form and of course it cannot track others' submittion (well this is a tricky one by chrome they do track the visits but it is not ethical) so I can only suggest you keep track the searches (or what form is doing) and on the home page list them as your latest 20 (100) searches with link so Google can easily crawl and other search engines of course. And for the performance don t list live latest list cache them like 5 mins or 10.

Comment: Disable javascript and see what happens. That will be closer to what search engines see.

Comment: I misstated my intent in my question. I'm not just interested in being crawl-able. The important pages change slow enough to use sitemaps and website submissions to SEs individually.

Answer (score 0):

Google does parse some JS, but you really need different URLs for different content.

That code looks like nothing I'd ever write, and nothing that anyone working with me/for me would be allowed to commit.

Build your site on stronger foundations.

Comment: I'm not a programmer, so I will refrain from comments about code creation standard, nonetheless I appreciate the frank opinion. The choice ultimately was to use method="post" and simply change the URL with each submission that results in a unique set of content. I hope to report any interesting SEO results next year.

Answer (score 0):

I found a good set of answers from the MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942833.aspx  Basically I need to either change to MVC or figure out a way to map the URLs to unique content.